# jQuery .live event handler does not work with multiple classes

Tags: jquery

This code adds the text liked inside `div.gdt-starrating`:

```
$("a.gdt-starrating").live("click", function() {
    $("div.gdt-starrating").text("liked");
});
```

But this code doesn't work (no text is added to `div.gdt-starrating`:

```
$("a.gdt-starrating").live("click", function() {
    $(".gdup div.gdt-starrating").text("liked");
});
```

Before clicking `a.gdt-starrating`:

```
<div id="gdsr_thumb_197_a_up" class="gdt-size-20 gdthumb gdup"><div class="gdt-starrating"></div></div>
```

After clicking `a.gdt-starrating`:

```
<div id="gdsr_thumb_197_a_up" class="gdt-size-20 gdthumb gdup"><a class="gdt-starrating"></div></div>
```

Why adding `.gdup` is making the thing not to work?

(Sorry for the title but I'm not pretty sure about the technical way of saying it).

Comment: div.gdt-starrating does not exist, or a.gdt-starrating does not exist...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is the correct way to use multiple class.

```
 $("div.gdt-starrating.gdup").text("liked");
```

if the class is of the same element, you do not seperate by space, but join by id, as above